# flutter firebase auth provider not notified

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I'm using flutter to do sign-in and register with email. My sign-in method works fine, and my sign-up (register) method is basically the same so they should have the same result, but the changes of user status in the register function do not notify the provider in the wrapper, so it cannot change to the home screen.

In AuthService the code is like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<User> get user {
print(_auth.authStateChanges());
return _auth.authStateChanges();
}

Future signInWithEP (String email, String password) async {
try{
  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  User user = result.user;
  return user;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}

Future signUpWithEP(String email, String password) async {
try{
  UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  User user = result.user;
  return user;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

In main.dart

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
    ),
    ],
  child: MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
      routes: {
        '/signin': (context) => SignIn(),
        '/register': (context) => Register(),
      },
    ),
```

In wrapper.dart,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
print("wrappper $user");

if(user == null) {
  return SignIn();
} else {
  return Home();
}
}
```

In both cases (sign-in and register), when clicking the button, it will show

```
D/FirebaseAuth( 4977): Notifying id token listeners about user ( some UID ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 4977): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( some UID ).
```

which, I believe probably means the user status is changed, but when sign-in it will print "wrapper" + user; in register function it will not, which means the provider in wrapper does not receive the change, and the home screen cannot be shown. Could anyone tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: Also after hot reload the home screen can be shown, which means the user status is indeed changed but just not timely shown in the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forget the notifyListeners() in yours methods

```
Future signInWithEP (String email, String password) async {
try{
  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  User user = result.user; 
notifyListeners(); // add here notify 
  return user;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

and here

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context)
```

change it to

```
final user =  context.watch<AuthUser>().user
```

Comment: This does not work, but thank you anyway!.
I found out my problem is I should not use routes while also using providers, in this case the provider is "scoped".